# how to get a valid understandable string from an hid device (barcode scanner) with evdev in python

Tags: python, linux, barcode-scanner, evdev

I've been trying to get string outputs from using a barcode scanner with evdev in python.
This was my script...

```
from evdev import *
dev = InputDevice('/dev/input/event2')

print(dev)

for event in dev.read_loop():
    if event.type == ecodes.EV_KEY:
        print(categorize(event))
```

And when I scan after this, I get this output:

```
key event at 1526024323.229556, 5 (KEY_4), down
key event at 1526024323.237564, 5 (KEY_4), up
key event at 1526024323.245549, 11 (KEY_0), down
key event at 1526024323.253534, 11 (KEY_0), up
key event at 1526024323.261553, 2 (KEY_1), down
key event at 1526024323.269538, 2 (KEY_1), up
key event at 1526024323.277549, 10 (KEY_9), down
key event at 1526024323.285565, 10 (KEY_9), up
key event at 1526024323.293555, 2 (KEY_1), down
key event at 1526024323.301535, 2 (KEY_1), up
key event at 1526024323.309553, 7 (KEY_6), down
key event at 1526024323.317533, 7 (KEY_6), up
key event at 1526024323.325553, 10 (KEY_9), down
key event at 1526024323.333537, 10 (KEY_9), up
key event at 1526024323.341554, 3 (KEY_2), down
key event at 1526024323.349537, 3 (KEY_2), up
key event at 1526024323.357552, 2 (KEY_1), down
key event at 1526024323.365537, 2 (KEY_1), up
key event at 1526024323.373554, 2 (KEY_1), down
key event at 1526024323.381535, 2 (KEY_1), up
key event at 1526024323.389555, 3 (KEY_2), down
key event at 1526024323.397535, 3 (KEY_2), up
key event at 1526024323.405552, 4 (KEY_3), down
key event at 1526024323.413537, 4 (KEY_3), up
key event at 1526024323.421554, 10 (KEY_9), down
key event at 1526024323.429537, 10 (KEY_9), up
key event at 1526024323.437579, 28 (KEY_ENTER), down
key event at 1526024323.445533, 28 (KEY_ENTER), up
```

I don't understand any of it, since I'm new to python, but I don't think that would make much difference in this case.
I have checked the other related questions but I could not make the answers from them work.
Please help me out guys.

How do I filter out the ups and keep the downs.

Comment: Looks pretty clear: Key 4 pressed, key 4 released, key 0 pressed, key 0 released. It's typing a sequence of numbers.

Comment: How do I filter out the ups and keep the downs?

Answer (score 0):

Barcode scanners often (always?) act as a keyboard. Scanning a barcode with a barcode scanner appears to the computer exactly the same as if you had a keyboard plugged in, typed the number and pressed enter.

If you have a command prompt or a text editor open and scan something, do you see the number appear as if you had typed it?

Usually you don't need to use a low level interface to interact with it - just use the built in `input()`

Comment: it worked very well on windows using the input function

Comment: How do I filter out the ups and keep the downs?

Comment: @PrakashGanesan input should work under linux - figuring out why it doesn't is probably the solution you actually want. In terms of filtering, check `keystate`: http://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apidoc.html#evdev.events.KeyEvent